# No trousers for them anymore in shortpants with Flatpickr + jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, flatpickr

How can these 4 lines be written in 2 lines?

```
$("#display_from").val(res.display_from);
$("#display_to").val(res.display_to);
flatpickr("#display_from", flatpickrconfig);
flatpickr("#display_to", flatpickrconfig);
```

A dumb bot gave me this:

```
$("#display_from").val(res.display_from).flatpickr(flatpickrconfig);
$("#display_to").val(res.display_to).flatpickr(flatpickrconfig);
```

Which does not work obviously:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).val(...).flatpickr is not a function
```

I repeat these same 4 lines all over the place. Someone help me cut their pants.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your code with brackets `($(selector).val('your-value')).flatpickr()` so that the input field is filled in before initializing flatpickr

```js
$(function() {
  let start = ($('#display_from').val('2023-02-01')).flatpickr();
  let end = $('#display_to').flatpickr();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.13/flatpickr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.13/flatpickr.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="display_from" />
<input type="text" id="display_to" />
```